# How to show Tickmark in Checkbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

I have a checkbox in my WPF application.

**XAML:**

```
 <CheckBox Content="Log Errors" IsChecked="{Binding IsLoggingRequired}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10" />
```

`ViewModel` has a property `IsLoggingRequired` based on which I will be doing the logging.

I need to display the checkbox with tick mark if the checkbox is checked just like below
[image: Normal checkbox]

But currently it is displaying like below. 
[image: WPF Checkbox]

I need checkbox with tick mark not a check box filled with some color. 
I am using Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Take a look at the [Check mark in a checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753143/check-mark-in-a-checkbox) post.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `IsThreeState` property to False

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `IsChecked` is not set to `null` and also set the `IsThreeState` to `False`..

Comment: Yes, I confirmed IsThreeState is false and IsChecked is true. If I set IsThreeState to true and IsChecked to null, I could see a checkbox with minus(-) sign, which is different from what I shared above.

Comment: Yes that the behaviour of the Checkbox.. what's your requirement?

Comment: My checkbox currently displayed as a square box filled with blue  color. I need a checkbox that can view like a tick mark inside a square.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look whether you have this viewModel,

```
private bool _islogged;

Public bool IsLogged
```

{

```
 get

{



return _islogged;

}





`set
```

`{` `

```
_islogged=value;` 

NotifyProperty("IsLogged");
```

}

}